# How to resolve SQL name conflict without renaming table attributes?

Tags: sql, database, derby

I am trying to create a table (shown below) for my final year project,
but I encountered SQL name conflict error. It seems the words 'User'
and 'role' are reserved by the SQL. Is there any way I can resolve the
issue, without renaming the words.

```
CREATE TABLE User
(
    ID INT generated by default as identity PRIMARY KEY,
    username varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    role varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put double quotes around User. In general it never hurts to quote all your identifiers.

Comment: I'm not sure quotes work, but square brackets seem to be the norm.

Comment: Hi Martin Krämer. Thank you very much I just test it and it works for perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Throw square brackets around their name (or any reserved word that you want as your column names).

[User]

or

[Role]

Answer (score 2):

Try this is you are using SQL Server(in MySql it can be done using `backticks` ``):

```
CREATE TABLE [User]
(
    ID INT generated by default as identity PRIMARY KEY,
    username varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    [role] varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

**On a side note:-** *It is not recommended to use reserved keywords for tabe name and column names.*

Use some other names like Users and Roles which are not reserved keyword and which have a similar namings.

**EDIT:**

After looking at your comments it looks like you are using Derby. So you need to use double quotes.

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE "User"
(
    ID INT generated by default as identity PRIMARY KEY,
    username varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    "role" varchar(255) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the exact command and it throws : Error code 30000, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "[" at line 1, column 14.
Line 1, column 1